# Function that returns the min value of a slice based on struct's field?

Tags: go

I've got a Go struct such as:

```
type patient struct{
    patientID int
    age int
    bodyTemp int
    numberVaccines int
    recordID int
}
```

How can I write a function that returns the min value in a slice of `patient` by selecting the field I'm interested in?

I'd call it like:

```
someSlice := []patient{patient{...},...,...}
fmt.Printf("Patient lowest temp: %v", someSlice.GetMin(bodyTemp)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. The minimum of what?

Comment: There is something important missing here.Your struct has ONE bodyTemp. So you want to get the mimimum of ONE value? That is your question like you described it here.

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad. Corrected the question.

Comment: You have to do some minimal amount of programming here.

Comment: What you're trying could be accomplished with reflection, but please don't do that. It's slow, and incredibly difficult to read. The right approach is one method per field.

Comment: @Flimzy got it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been already written in the comments, you can do it using reflection, but there is no need to do that due to performance decrease.

**Option 1**

As for a quick solution, I suggest you to implement a patients slice wrapper that is responsible to keep and find the data you need by criteria specified (for each field its own method). This is also not about a performance, because in your case you need to search a minimum value that has O(N) complexity (you need to iterate all the items in the slice).

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

var (
    ErrPatientsContainerIsEmpty = errors.New("patients container is empty")
)

type Patient struct{
    patientID int
    age int
    bodyTemp int
    numberVaccines int
    recordID int
}

type PatientsContainer struct {
    patients []Patient
}

func NewPatientsContainer() *PatientsContainer {
    patients := make([]Patient, 0)
    return & PatientsContainer{
        patients: patients,
    }
}

func (pc *PatientsContainer) Add(p Patient) {
    pc.patients = append(pc.patients, p)
}

func (pc *PatientsContainer) WithMinTemp() (*Patient, error) {
    if len(pc.patients) == 0 {
        return nil, ErrPatientsContainerIsEmpty
    }

    patientWithMinTemp := &pc.patients[0]

    // O(N) complexity!
    for i, p := range pc.patients {
        if p.bodyTemp < patientWithMinTemp.bodyTemp {
            patientWithMinTemp = &pc.patients[i]
        }
    }

    return patientWithMinTemp, nil
}

func main() {
    // some patients data for testing
    patients := []Patient{
        {
            recordID: 1,
            bodyTemp: 37,
        },
        {
            recordID: 2,
            bodyTemp: 36,
        },
            {
            recordID: 3,
            bodyTemp: 38,
        },  
    }

    pc := NewPatientsContainer()

    // Add to container
    for _, p := range patients {
        pc.Add(p)
    }

    patientWithMinTemp, err := pc.WithMinTemp()
    if err != nil {
        // handle an error
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(patientWithMinTemp.recordID)
}
```

**Option 2**

If we are talking about an application with a big dataset (not 50 patients), the correct way is to introduce to the application a storage that supports indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sort.Slice function documented here: https://pkg.go.dev/sort

```
patients := []patient{patient{...},...,...}    
sort.Slice(patients, func(i, j int) bool {
   return patients[i].bodyTemp < patients[j].bodyTemp
})
minBodyTempPatient := patients[0]
```